# Homogenize ggplot abscissa size for 2 plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare two variables against the X axis by displaying them on the same column.

For some reasons (not technical question), I can't display both variables on the same graph.

When I display these two variables with different unit ranges with `ggarrange`, the one with the largest numbers appears to have more space for y labels and less space for the graph (lower abscissa size).

Do you know how I could display both graphs having the same greyzone size (same abscissa size)?

Thank you

```
### Import library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

### Initiating data
dfTemp <- 
  data.frame(
    Xaxis=1:100,
    Variable1=rnorm(100, 100, 10),
    Variable2=rnorm(100, 1000000, 100000)
      )

### Initiating plots
scatterPlot1 <- 
  ggplot(data=dfTemp, aes(x=Xaxis, y=Variable1)) + 
  geom_line()
scatterPlot2 <- 
  ggplot(data=dfTemp, aes(x=Xaxis, y=Variable2)) + 
  geom_line()

### Display plots
ggarrange(scatterPlot1,
          scatterPlot2,
          nrow=2, ncol=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `align` argument

```
dfTemp <- 
  data.frame(
    Xaxis=1:100,
    Variable1=rnorm(100, 100, 10),
    Variable2=rnorm(100, 1000000, 100000)
  )

### Initiating plots
scatterPlot1 <- 
  ggplot(data=dfTemp, aes(x=Xaxis, y=Variable1)) + 
  geom_line()
scatterPlot2 <- 
  ggplot(data=dfTemp, aes(x=Xaxis, y=Variable2)) + 
  geom_line()

### Display plots
ggarrange(scatterPlot1,
          scatterPlot2,
          nrow=2, ncol=1, align = "v")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to glueing multiple plots together it's always worthwhile to consider `patchwork` as an option:

```
library(patchwork)

scatterPlot1 / 
  scatterPlot2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this library and it works perfectly for this example.
For my real data, it works nicely even though it now created a little space on the right of my graph with the largest labels. I will investigate if there is a solution to fix this small issue.

Comment: Yup. `patchwork` is good to know. But the same is true for ggarrange. (; There are always cases where one works better than the other.